# How to use Keyword to make a list of file paths

Tags: vba

I am a new to VBA and do not have any formal training but have been able to do a few thing by copy and modify code to what I need. I need some help to modify this one. As it stand now this puts all the file path in the column A for all files that are in the folder. What I am looking to do is just get the files path of the files that contain a keyword. Thank you for any help you can give me.

```
Sub File_List()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\user\temp")
i = 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Comment: What type(s) of files ?  Keywords in the content of the files, or the file names ?

Comment: First thank you for the help. The files are .pdf .doc .txt (could be more type later on) . The Keyword would only be for the file name. Right now I have a Excel sheet that runs the code above and pulls all of the file names then the sheet is setup (with the normal Excel search and match commands) to find witch ones have the Keyword in it. I am trying to do the same thing just with VBA. The folder that I am pulling from had 2000 + files and growing

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instr() to check if the keyword is in the filename:

```
If Len(InStr(1, objFile.Path, "KEYWORD", vbTextCompare)) > 0 Then
```

InStr returns the Position of the substring if it is found, if not, it will return 0.
Use this in the For Each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub File_List()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\user\temp")
    i = 1

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFile.Name) Like "*keywordhere*" Then
            Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Path
            Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next objFile

End Sub
```